# Does collapsible js accept css icon content: "content: "\e622"";?

Tags: js-css, page-content

I get blank space when I insert content: "\e622"; and I get the plus sign when i enter content: "+";.

Comment: It's actually on Magento 2, http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_collapsible.html#fedg_collaps_icons

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was under the impression that this was a third party jQuery library, not Magentos own code. **Close vote retracted.**